Nifi nodes cannot communicate with each other
.nifi.controller.StandardFlowService Failed to connect to cluster due to: org.apache.nifi.cluster.protocol.ProtocolException: Failed marshalling 'CONNECTION_REQUEST' protocol message due to: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
I have checked the logs for nifi-1 and nifi-2 where we are having the issues
